# Spring boot Embedded Jetty server Communication Port Security

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, web-applications, jetty, tls1.2

i want to configure server.ssl.protocol=TLS1.2 but i dont keep kesytore on server. Before my application we have f5 load balancer which does SSL offloading. so from load balacer to application traffic is http.

how can i make sure all request from app are using TSLv1.2 ???

more Info::

```
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

are the settings That needs to be enabled for secure port communication. 
since app is after f5 load balancer it does not need any keystore in  app server.all traffic will be offloaded and frowarded in http to App.
now i dont have keystore on app what are possible ways we can enable server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2. because when i enable 
app start fails with below error: since there is  no keystore , is their way to read .pem or any other  instead of jks.

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load
>   key store 'null'  at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>     at com.americanexpress.mfservices.bootClass.main(bootClass.java:19)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException:
>   Could not load key store 'null'   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslServerCustomizer.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.configureSsl(SslServerCustomizer.java:162)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.customize(SslServerCustomizer.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource
>   location must not be null     at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)  at
>   org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslServerCustomizer.java:188)
>     ... 14 more

Comment: This is more of a F5 configuration question, you'll want F5 to handle the TLSv1.2, and to relay the forwarding and certificate details of the connection to the Jetty server via request headers. (headers that Jetty can use to test for `HttpServletRequest.isSecure()`)

Comment: so i am using Spring Rest Controller and Embedded Server. i am thinking is their way we can do something with application.properties. in below can we have like pem file instead of JKS . i am only able to get docs based on jks keystore                                                               #server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
##server.ssl.key-store-password=password
##server.ssl.key-alias=jetty
##server.ssl.key-password=password
##server.ssl.key-store=keystorepath
##server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
#server.ssl.protocol=TLS
#server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2

Comment: If F5 is handling the SSL/TLS, the backend Jetty cannot also handle it for the same client, it will wind up being a new connection from the F5 to the Jetty with it's own connection, it's own SSL/TLS negotiation, etc.  The details of the SSL/TLS from the Client to F5 layer will be overridden by the F5 to Server layer.   Is that what you want?